# Classes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react classes inside my HTML file. Everything works fine if I have this.state inside the class constructor. But if I want to do it outside of the constructor such as state= {key: value, key2: value2 ...}, it doesn't work. Actually, it seems that I am not able to use anything but methods inside my class (outside of the constructor.) It gives "Unexpected token" and puts a little arrow below the assignment operator "=". When I use create-react-app, all the problems go away, so I am curious why referencing inside the HTML causes this?

Comment: My problem is that logOut() { this.setState({loggedIn: false})  } outside of constructor works fine but  var logOut= function() { this.setState({loggedIn: false})  } does not work. (Note there is this.logOut=this.logOut.bind(this) inside the constructor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use class properties which is [not yet part of javascript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), you can install a babel plugin to enable this feature. Simply run

```
npm install @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
```

then add it to your .babelrc config file so it should look like this

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
}
```

**Note**: if you're using a CDN instead of a build tool such as webpack, then you should use [babel-standalone](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone) CDN not babel-core like so:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

create-react-app installs this plugin, which is why it works for you when you generate a react app with create-react-app.

Comment: Hello, I tried doing it but it did not resolve my problem. Also, please consider, I have <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.29/browser.js"></script> inside my HTML.

Comment: I just edited the answe, the babel-standalone cdn should work for you i just tested it and class properties is working.

Comment: Could you check my comment to the question please, I specified my exact problem. I did all the steps above including babel-standalone but it still gives me 'Unexpected token' if I use = outside of the constructor. I tried it with create-react-app and it works so I am curious as to why I can't make it work.

Comment: Did you read the modified version of the answer ? 
I added the correct CDN at the end, for people who use a CDN instead of the build tool.
Here's the CDN you should use for babel
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

Comment: The CDN you mentioned in your comment is the babel-core CDN
you should use the babel-standalone CDN, i tried it and it works